# every non-principal ultrafilter contains a cofinite filter.

Tags: general-topology, filters

I have several questions regarding filters and ultrafilters:

> (a) **Does every non-principal ultrafilter contain a cofinite filter? Why?**
>
> (b) **What is the difference between a Fréchet filter and a cofinite filter?**
>
> (c) **Can we say "an ultrafilter is free iff it contains a Fréchet filter"? Why?**

Comment: The Frechet filter and the cofinite filter, in the usual definition, are the same.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, every non-principal ultrafilter on an infinite set $X$ contains the cofinite filter on $X$. Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a non-principal ultrafilter on $X$, and let $x\in X$ be arbitrary. Since $\mathscr{U}$ is an ultrafilter, exactly one of the sets $\{x\}$ and $X\setminus\{x\}$ belongs to $\mathscr{U}$, and since $\mathscr{U}$ is non-principal, $\{x\}\notin\mathscr{U}$. Thus, $X\setminus\{x\}\in\mathscr{U}$ for each $x\in X$. Now let $F$ be any finite subset of $X$; then $$X\setminus F=\bigcap_{x\in F}\left(X\setminus\{x\}\right)$$ is the intersection of finitely many members of $\mathscr{U}$. Every filter is closed under finite intersections, so $X\setminus F\in\mathscr{U}$. The cofinite filter on $X$ is precisely $\{X\setminus F:F\subseteq X\text{ is finite}\}$, so we’ve just shown that $\mathscr{U}$ contains the cofinite filter on $X$.

*Fréchet filter* and *cofinite filter* are two names for the same thing; there is no difference.

Yes, an ultrafilter on $X$ is free iff it contains the Fréchet filter on $X$. In the first paragraph I proved that every free ultrafilter on $X$ contains the Fréchet filter on $X$. For the converse, suppose that $\mathscr{U}$ is a fixed ultrafilter on $X$; then there is an $x\in X$ such that $\{x\}\in\mathscr{U}$. But then $X\setminus\{x\}$ is an element of the Fréchet filter that is **not** in $\mathscr{U}$, so $\mathscr{U}$ does not contain the Fréchet filter.

Comment: Dear Brain M.scott, you let $F$ to be a finite subset of $X$ right. But the fact that it's finite is not used anywhere in the proof. In other words, if $F$ be an infinite set then I believe doing the process what you have done with the finite subset will again lead to result that $X \setminus F$ also belongs to $\mathscr{U}$ where in this case $F$ is an infinite set. Please let know if I am wrong, I really want to understand the proof.

Comment: @RAHUL: The fact that $F$ is finite *is* used in the proof. Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a filter, and let $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$. It follows immediately from the definition of *filter* that if $\mathscr{A}$ is finite, then $\bigcap\mathscr{A}\in\mathscr{U}$. (You should prove this, if you’ve not seen a proof.) If $\mathscr{A}$ is infinite, however, it is **not** generally true that $\bigcap{A}\in\mathscr{U}$; indeed, if $\mathscr{A}$ is infinite, it’s entirely possible that $\bigcap\mathscr{A}=\varnothing$ which is certainly not in $\mathscr{U}$. In my proof here $\mathscr{A}$ is ...

Comment: ... the family $\big\{X\setminus\{x\}:x\in F\big\}$ of subsets of $X$. Each of these sets $X\setminus\{x\}$ belongs to $\mathscr{U}$, so $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{U}$. Moreover, $F$ is finite, so $\mathscr{A}$ is finite, and therefore $\bigcap\mathscr{A}\in\mathscr{U}$. But $\bigcap\mathscr{A}=X\setminus F$, so $X\setminus F\in\mathscr{U}$. If $F$ were not finite, $\mathscr{A}$ would not be finite, and I could not conclude that $\bigcap\mathscr{A}$ (i.e., $X\setminus F$) belonged to $\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: Sir, What does $\bigcap\mathscr{A}$ mean? Is it intersection of all such $A$ or is it something else?

Comment: @RAHUL: If $\mathscr{A}$ is any family of sets, $\bigcap\mathscr{A}$ is the intersection of all of the members of $\mathscr{A}$. For instance, if $\mathscr{A}=\{A_i:i\in I\}$, then $$\bigcap\mathscr{A}=\bigcap\{A_i:i\in I\}=\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i\,.$$