# Does every free filter contain the cofinite filter?

Tags: general-topology, filters

In the answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476289/every-non-principal-ultrafilter-contains-a-cofinite-filter) a free ultrafilter is shown to contain the cofinite filter.

But does every free filter contain it too? Obviously the ultrafilter that extend it does.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, every free filter $\mathscr{F}$ contains the cofinite filter. Since $\mathscr{F}$ is free, for every $x$, there is an $F_x \in \mathscr{F}$ with $x\notin F_x$. For every finite set $M = \{x_1,\dotsc,x_n\}$, the set

$$F_M = \bigcap_{k=1}^n F_{x_k}$$

belongs to $\mathscr{F}$, as it is a finite intersection of filter sets. Hence it follows that $\complement M \in \mathscr{F}$, since $\complement M \supset F_M$, thus $\mathscr{F}$ contains all cofinite sets.

Comment: $F_x$ is just a set that belongs to the free filter $\mathscr{F}$. Let me expand.

Comment: I just figured that out now.