# cofinite filter is intersection of all non-principal ultrafilter

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

It is clear that Cofinite filter on any infinite set is contained in every non-principal ultrafilter so it is contained in the intersection of all non-principal ultrafilters, but my question is that Is Cofinite filter the intersection of all non-principal ultrafilters?

Comment: In other words, you want to know if every infinite set belongs to some non-principal ultrafilter?

Comment: Did you roll a die to decide the tags for this question?

Comment: What does this have to do with geometric group theory? (your tags)

Comment: it is used in the theory of asymptotic cones, which was the key ingredient in proof of Gromov's theorem on groups of polynomial growth

Comment: I feel like that is stretching what tags are used for, given that it doesn't seem like there is any geometric group theory in this question. (a lot more questions would be tagged ggt if some idea, tool, or technique, in the question, was used at some point in the area).

Comment: I just added  because people from ggt background know these things and they can quickly answer my question

Comment: Surely people from geometric group theory can answer basic questions about intersection and union of sets. Should we start tagging all discrete mathematics questions with these tags also?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476289/every-non-principal-ultrafilter-contains-a-cofinite-filter and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676765/does-every-free-filter-contain-the-cofinite-filter

Answer (score 5):

Let $E$ be an infinite set. Suppose that a set $A\subseteq E$ belongs to every non-principal ultrafilter on $E;$ we want to show that $A$ is cofinite.

Assume for a contradiction that $A$ is not cofinite, i.e., the set $B=E\setminus A$ is infinite. Then the infinite set $B$ belongs to some non-principal ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $E.$ But then $\mathcal U$ is a non-principal ultrafilter on $E$ which does not contain $A,$ contradicting our assumption that $A$ belongs to every non-principal ultrafilter.

**why this infinite set B belongs to some non-principal ultrafilter**

Let $\mathcal F=\{X\subseteq E:\ E\setminus X\text{ is finite}\},$ the cofinite filter on$E.$ Then the collection $\{B\}\cup\mathcal F$ has the finite intersection property, whence $\{B\}\cup\mathcal F\subset\mathcal U$ for some ultrafilter $\mathcal U.$ Since $\mathcal U$ contains $\mathcal F,$ it is non-principal.

Comment: why this infinite set B belongs to son non-principal ultrafilter